# Configuration of web services with httpster NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on some demo project where i am using following Node NPM's

- httpster
- express

I have installed httpster in my system at global level, my project directory is `D:\Project\Demo\Node` which content following files & dir.

```
/Node
 - index.html
 - style.css
 - server.js
```

I have written all my services method in these server.js file. 
Following is the content of my server.js file

```
var express   = require('express')
  , http      = require('http')
  , app       = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.set(express.methodOverride());
    app.set(express.router);
});


app.get('/', function() {
    sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM users_tbl").success(function(rows) {
        console.log(rows);
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    sequelize.query("INSERT INTO users_tbl (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('"+req.body.firstname+"','"+req.body.lastname+"')").success(function() {
        console.log("Data Inserted");
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    sequelize.query("UPDATE users_tbl SET lastname='"+req.body.lastname+"' WHERE id='"+req.params.id+"'").success(function() {
        console.log("Data Updated");
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

app.del('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    sequelize.query("DELETE FROM users_tbl WHERE id='"+req.params.id+"'").success(function() {
        console.log("Data Delete");
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

to run my project I simply navigate to my project folder as below

```
cd "d:\Project\Demo\Node\"
```

and run httpster command and it run under the default port 3333

```
http://localhost:3333   => reads my index.html successfully, but no service is run.
http://localhost:3333/user  => this too don't work.
```

I guess, my httpster have no reference with my server.js. So how do i use my services with httpster npm?

Comment: I want to run my project which is in Backbone & my service in Node, ExpressJS at a single localhost port. Is it correct way I am thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

httpster only serves static content. So what you're doing is create a 'static' server letting you access to those 3 files from a browser.
But it will never execute server.js

if you want server.js to be executed, you have to call node server.js

But if you already use express, why do you want to use httpster?
You just have to include a line like

```
app.use(express.static(path));
```

to serve all your static files

Comment: Yes! I got it, I did not had this line. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! you are correct there is no need of HTTPSter when there is Express